# How can I control which samples are read using tfrecords and steps_per_epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am currently transitioning my tf code towards tfrecords and tf datasets. In my application, the trained model usually converges long before it has seen all training samples. I therefore usually set the data generator length myself to the number of batches that I want to fit in one epoch and ensure in my generator that in the next epoch, the generator picks up after the last sample from the previous epoch. This allows that all callbacks work as desired (especially early stopping) while I can still train my models with unseen data in each epoch.

How can I achieve this behaviour with tf datasets and tfrecords? I have read through the dataset definitions on the tensorflow Github but am unsure on whether this will be possible.

I think there are two possible solutions to this if I set `steps_per_epoch`:

1. Overwriting the part of the code that specifies from where the next sample is read to just pick up at the sample one after the last one from the previous epoch.
2. Trying to mimic the behaviour described above with a custom tf dataset implementation. I would be worried that this could have unforeseen impacts on parallelisations and performance.

However, I do not know how to accomplish either. So if you have any insights on this, I would be very grateful.

For now I can use an inelegant work-around in which I always train for one epoch and then initialise a new dataset with new tfrecord files, but I hope there is a better way, especially with regards to callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand what you try to achieve. You want that:

- During an epoch, your model does NOT see the whole dataset
- The following epochs do not use samples from the previous ones

That's it?

From my point of view, the `steps_per_epoch` argument is your best bet. If you have a Dataset with, for example, 100 items (samples or batches) and you set `steps_per_epoch=20` then, during the first epoch your model will see items 0 to 19, and 20 to 39 during second epoch, and so on. No need to overwrite any part of code.

Trying to mimic the Dataset behavior is probably not a good idea (too many things to take care, many (hard) work involved).

From your last paragraph, I understand that you want each epoch to be feeded with data from specific TFRecord files. Maybe you can look at [`tf.data.Dataset.flat_map`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#flat_map). Build a list of your TFRecord files (same file can appear multiple times) and "`flat_map`" `TFRecordDataset` on it:

```py
files = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([
   "file1.tfrecord", "file2.tfrecord",
   "file1.tfrecord", "file3.tfrecord"
])
dataset = file.flat_map(TFRecordDataset)
```

Iterating over dataset will give you `Example`s from file1, then from file2, then from file1 again and then from file3.

Hope this can help.

Comment: Hello Alexis, 
thank you for your response! So that sounds like the default behaviour might already be what I want. If I understand correctly, if I set `steps_per_epoch`, the data set will still iterate through all the data before it "runs out" of new examples? Is there a way to verify this? I am worried that with the parallelisation, several `tfrecord` files are read at the same time, then if the epoch ends, new files are randomly selected and the samples that are "deeper in the file" never get read. But this might be a misunderstanding that I have regarding how parallelisation works here.

Comment: From what I experimented, yes the default behaviour is what you want. To verify it, you can try to build a very simple model with a single layer using `tf.print` in its call method. Than run `model.fit(dataset, steps_per_epoch=n, verbose=2)`. About the parallelism, it depends on how you build your dataset. By default, with `TFRecordDataset` there is no parallelism (see the `num_parallel_reads` argument), and `flat_map` run sequentially too (compared to the `interleave`) method.

Comment: Hi, yes, I could approximately verify that this should indeed be the desired behaviour - I could not find duplicates when printing a data set that has each label only once and the number of samples before an error was thrown due to end of data set matches the number that I expect. Thank you for clarifying!